# Z axis of mapping node in Shader is not working

Tags: shaders

[image]

As you can see in the picture above, touching the values ​​of the X and Y axes moves the texture, but touching the Z value does not move the texture. What should I do?

i have new problem. please show below picture.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your image is the same for all Z values, because images have no **depth**. What result are you expecting, what is it that you actually want to do?

Comment: it's moving but you can't see it because the projection is flat, if in the Image Texture you choose Box instead of Flat you'll see the texture moving

Answer (score 1):

It's moving but you can't see it because the projection is flat, it means that the image is only projected on the object local Z axis and therefore on the side you'll only see the stretched pixels of the picture. If in the *Image Texture* you choose *Box* instead of *Flat* you'll see the texture projected on the sides and you'll be able to move it.

[image]

But keep in mind that even with the *Box* option, if you rotate your image, it will stretch it. It's not because it is projected on its face that it can't be stretched if you rotate it.

[image]

Comment: Thanks to your answers I could solve the problem. By the way i have new problem. If i rotate image by using Mapping node, only part of face move. how can i solve it?

Comment: what do you mean exactly when you say part of face? maybe edit your first question and show some screenshots. Also you should find some tutorials about how the mapping works and how to deal with the 3 axis...

Comment: I'm sorry for the late reply. I guess you didn't quite understand my question. I've attached a new GIF to the top. As you can see from the new GIF image, if i rotate image of object, only part of face move. Can you still answer that?

Comment: your gif is hard to follow, please tell what you're doing exactly with the Mapping node

Comment: okay. i updated new viedo. as video explain, if images of object is not rotated, image of every face is moving. But if image of object is rotated, only image of some face is moving. how to sovle this problem? i edited video upl : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XkK48nu3EBI

Comment: if you rotate your image 90°, what I've explained on my first picture happens again, the pixels are stretched on one of your axis. Also, maybe you must keep in mind that maybe your local axis is not aligned on the global axis.

Comment: So do you mean i must allign axis about image? but how? could you tell me how to do?

Comment: What is your goal exactly? If you don't want any stretching please read my answer again, if you want something else, please be more specific

Comment: Yes, my goal is to follow your answers to the my questions with YouTube videos attached. But you explained it only in text, so I don't understand. So, I'm sorry, but could you answer to me a solution process described by video or images?

Comment: could you please share the plank object? Just make sure you've packed the image, go in File > External Data > Pack All Into Blend. Use https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: sure. i uploaded my blend. file on main text.

Comment: Ok I understand your problem, I've edited the answer. It's not because it is projected on each face that it can't be stretched if you rotate it. Also don't forget things like applying the scale (ctrl A), it will avoid other texture deformations that you may don't understand.

Comment: Yes, I saw your new photo. So how do I solve that problem? I can't find picture to solve this problem. did i miss something? perhaps is it solved when I apply scale (ctrl + A) to object? but although i apply scale (ctrl + A) to object, it didn't solved. if you don't upload, could you upload a picture of how to solve problem?

Comment: You just need to let the Rotation at 0°. If you're not glad with the result you need to find another texturing method: Either create a procedural texture (meaning without the use of any image so you'll have to use nodes like Noise etc), or unwrap your plank and put the UV over the image.

Comment: Aha, Now I see. Thank you for your sincere answer. It was a great help.